# Undocking a code window in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I've finally joined the 21st century and got a second monitor. I can merrily undock all the side windows (Solution Explorer, ToolBox etc) and plonk them anywhere I like on either monitor. I can't though figure out how to undock a code window. Is it possible? (I'm using vs2008).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Just for you](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/05/multi-monitor-bliss.html) (VS2010) ;-p

[image: Multi Monitor Bliss]

Comment: Wasn't the question in regard to VS2008?

Comment: It was - and looking at the answers I assumed it wasn't available pre 2010.

Comment: Indeed - to clarify: it isn't available until 2010; I can't do much about that ;-p

Comment: check out my answer, StudioTools (a free addin) can do what you need in VS2008

Answer (score 1):

Multi monitor is a key functionality of the new vs 2010 as was requested by a lot of devs.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is a way to do that.
You just need to install a FREE addon from Exact Magic named [StudioTools](http://www.exactmagic.com/products/studiotools/index.html)
It has this feature called "Tear Off Editor Window".
You just activate the tab you want to tear off and from the StudioTools manu select Tear Off Editor.

I also strongly recommend you check out the rest of the features, especially the "Smart Goto" which rocks!

Comment: StudioTools seems to be broken for me in VS 2005. The arrow keys and Backspace do not work in the floating code windows. It might be a conflict with other plugins I have installed (ReSharper, RockScroll, etc.).

Comment: Possible, can you please post your findings when you investigate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could resize Visual Studio to cover both monitors, then right-click the code window and click New Vertical Tab Group

Answer (score 0):

The "Tear Off Editor Window" feature in Studio Tools from Exact Magic is I think the only option if can't just extend the application over your monitors, if you have multiple monitors of different sizes or a mix of portrait and landscape orientation.

However you cannot download Studio Tools from the original site as they were bought by another company who no longer support the software. You can download it from the the Wayback Machine: [Studio Tools Download Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20090225105754/http://www.exactmagic.com:80/products/studiotools/actions/download.html)