# Create DUPLICATE code window in visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I want one code window to have two duplicates. I want to place one code window on one monitor, and second code window on the second, extended monitor.
As I Go on typing, I want second window to display the code that I type on the first monitor. Is it possible in visual studio 2012?
It would be very helpful for me while teaching the trainees.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/893388/undocking-a-code-window-in-visual-studio

Comment: Its a great day for me, as I finally earned 125 reputation..Took long time for me, But its proud. Thanks to that anonymous who up voted this question to bring me to 125! God bless you, Thank you StackOverflow.com

Comment: @gvee Well, the problem is that sometime I don't remember the entire code, Also, I don't want trainees to see entire code at first. So If I use extend option, then I can type in VS of other monitor that is exposed to audience without making them aware that I am typing the code by READING / copying it :)
Actually I created my own small application that replicates text typed. But that app won't run the code written nor shows intellisense :) Hence I want it from VS2012,

Comment: You mean you simple want to clone desktops?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter Nope, I want to clone the code window. Not desktop.

Comment: This option no more works in Visual studio 2013...Very disappointing :(

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I haven't got a copy installed here to test but I believe the answer you're looking for lies hidden under the `Window` menu..

Activate the window you wish to duplicate and under `Window` on the toolbar choose **New Window**. This will create a duplicate of the active document. Under the `Window` menu again you should find the option to make the window **Floating**

**Update for Visual Studio 2013:** [Vertical split of cshtml window in VS2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20463812/vertical-split-of-cshtml-window-in-vs2013)

Comment: The "New window" Windows menu item should be called "Duplicate window"!

Comment: This option no more works in Visual studio 2013...Very disappointing :(

Comment: @AdityaBokade possible solution for 2013: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20463812/vertical-split-of-cshtml-window-in-vs2013

Answer (score 1):

In VS2012, the feature closest to what you are after is called "Split" and its under the Window menu when you have a code file selected. This creates a split view of the selected code file within the original window.

I don't know of any way to seperate the copies from each other and float them on different screens.

Comment: This was the solution I was looking for. Its a great way to duplicate the code window. However, it would be nice to be able to float the duplicate window.