# How to display two classes at the same time with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I need to see and edit multiple classes at the same time.
With Eclipse I can achieve it with drag&drop.

Is it possible with Visual Studio 2013 Express and how?

Something similar to this:

[image]

Comment: http://www.kevinwilliampang.com/2008/08/19/visual-studio-tip-split-views/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split a window by dragging an almost-invisible handle at the top down, this shows you 2 areas for the code. I don't think you can do it side-by-side however, unless you undock the code window for one of the files you're working on and position it to the side.

Answer (score 3):

With at least two files open, you can use the "Window->New Vertical Tab Group" or "New Horizontal Tab Group".

This will create a new pane and you can move tabs between them.

You can do the same with a single file by using 'Window->New Window'. That creates a second view of the same file and you can then split as a separate group.

Comment: This is the method I use almost every day. Especially when writing unit tests, I have the test in one window and the Unit under test in the other tab to reference as I write the "arrange" part of the test. I voted it up.

Comment: @fpintos, why I can do only horizontal and not vertical tab group?

Answer (score 0):

You can dock one code window to the side of another. Marc Gravell's answer below to a similar question shows how:

[Undocking a code window in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893388/undocking-a-code-window-in-visual-studio)